# Reading Avro/Parquet Files using Talend

Tags: amazon-s3, avro, talend

I am trying to move data from AWS S3 with flat files(avro or parquet) in Talend.  What component shall I use to read/extract it? Im using Talend DI v8. I've tried tFileInputDelimited but only reads csv or txt. Not sure if Im configuring it correctly.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You didn’t see the standard component?  https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/parquet/tfileinputparquet

Comment: I can't find this tfileinputparquet or tavroinput in my Talend DI.  Do I need to install it manually or does it require an enterprise version?  I'm only using the free version.

Comment: maybe use tFileinputRaw (will return  an object )  -> tConvertType (convert the object to a String if that s what you want ) .to See result just paste a tLogRow after to check

Comment: Try using Talend Bigdata version of the studio